# Returning a "Java" New Line in a String?

Tags: java, linux, string, unix, newline

This may be a simple question, but I was unable to find anything resembling the topic:

I have a program that needs to be run in Linux, and Windows.  As you know, Windows new line character is `\r\n`, and in Linux/Unix it is `\n` (Mac is `\r`).

When I need to print anything to a file or to the command line, I can use println() function to create a new line.  This works fine, but I need to return many new line characters as Strings so that I can for example use them more than once, modify them, etc. (I can also use find-replace to replace all my `\r\n` at the same time.)

The windows character `\r\n` I am using currently prints `^M` in Linux.

Is there a character, or method I can use to return new lines in Strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use   `System.lineSeparator()` it works in all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` that returns system specific line separator.